# THREE.js repeating UV texture using JSONLoader

Tags: three.js, blender

I need help for getting UV Textures to be rendered correctly in three.js. I've created a model with repeating tile texture in Blender. The tile texture is applied using UV mapping, and it looks like this if it is being rendered correctly:
[Render image using Blender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUVFP.jpg)
.However, when it is loaded using JSONLoader by three.js, the tiles are just stretched to fill each polygon, giving weird result like this:[Screenshot of render using three.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHDJI.png)
. I've tried setting THREE.RepeatWrapping in my code but nothing changed:

```
bodyLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
bodyLoader.load('./starofthesea_threejs.json', function(geometry, materials) {
  mainBodyMaterials = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
  console.log(materials);
  mainBodyMaterials.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  mainBodyMaterials.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  mainBodyMaterials.needsUpdate = true;
  mainBody = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mainBodyMaterials);
  mainBody.traverse ( function (child) {
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
      child.castShadow = true;
      child.receiveShadow = true;
    }
  });
  mainBody.scale.x = mainBody.scale.y = mainBody.scale.z = 1;
  geometry.computeBoundingBox();
  geometry.computeFaceNormals();
  geometry.computeFlatVertexNormals();
  scene.add(mainBody);

});
```

Is there anything wrong in my code, or workaround to get it rendered correctly? All help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought, do you need to set the mainBodyMaterials.repeat.set( 10, 10 ); and do the textures need to be power of 2 width height?

Comment: Setting repeat on material just throws an 'undefined' error, and all the dimension of the textures are set to be power of 2 already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've figured out the problem by myself, where both the Blender model and JS are misconfigured. RepeatWrapping should be **applied to texture** but not material. I need to study the structure of THREE.MeshFaceMaterial to find the handle for the underlying textures. I need to traverse through the materials to find out all materials with image textures:

```
mainBodyMaterials = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
for(prop in mainBodyMaterials.materials) {
  if(mainBodyMaterials.materials[prop].map != null) {
    mainBodyMaterials.materials[prop].map.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    mainBodyMaterials.materials[prop].map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    tex.push(mainBodyMaterials.materials[prop].map.clone());
    tex[tex_sequence].needsUpdate = true;
    tex_sequence++;
  }
}
```

After applying wrapS and wrapT to textures correctly, one of the tile materials get rendered correctly, but 'Texture marked for update but image is undefined' error keep throwing out. I need to clone the texture to get rid of the error, according to another question: [Three.js r72 - Texture marked for update but image is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984599/three-js-r72-texture-marked-for-update-but-image-is-undefined)
As there are several materials with repeating tiles, I need to create a global array at the beginning of the JS routine, and push the modified textures one by one when looping through the materials:

```
var tex = new Array();
var tex_sequence = 0;
```

After fixing the JS calls, one of the textures are still not working. I forgot that only **ONE** UV slot is allowed for three.js. I need to unwrap the UVs again under the same UV slot in Blender. Everything works like a charm, and I hope my painful experience can help those who are getting mad by similar problems.